# Modifying an item in a WPF sorted ListView doesn't change the sort position of that item

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a sortable listview that gets filled with a live data as it comes. Sorting works perfectly but the real problem arises when an item is modified after being added to the collection. The position of modified item does not change no matter what the sort orders is.

I have googled it but couldn't find a better solution to make my listview a perfect sorted listview.

Solutions??

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using for the sorting when the data comes in?

Comment: @Tony - well code is too much to be posted here.. But the problems seems to be with any sortable listview sample avialable on net.

Comment: We really can't help unless we know how you're populating the `ListView`. Are you adding items to an `ObservableCollection` that the `ListView` uses as a source? Are you adding the items to the `ListView` in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are following an approach similar to [this MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786.aspx).  If so, then sorting happens based on the collection view's SortDescriptions.  As long as the source collection is observable, the sort order should be respected when items are added or removed from the collection.

The real problem arises when an item is modified *after* being added to the collection.  In that case, the collection is not automatically re-sorted.

I explain the issue in detail in ['E' is for Editable Collection](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection/) (in my [ItemsControl A to Z](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) series).  I also present a few workarounds that offer different levels of performance.  The most drastic is to force a re-sort of the entire collection by calling Refresh() on the CollectionView.  If possible, I would avoid that and use a better option, like implementing IEditableObject on your items and issuing an Edit() followed by Commit() whenever the properties change on an item.